# Parsing Json containing escape characters to JsonObject using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to parse json string to JsonObject but I'm having exception ("Bad JSON escape sequence: \x. Path 'original_query', line 8, position 35.")

I know there are bad characters in my JSON String but I'm not able to escape that characters.

Here is my working:

```
String json =  File.ReadAllText("json.txt");

JObject json = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Here is json file data:

```
{
"original_query" : "[currency == \x22USD\x22 \x26 ((exchange == \x22NASDAQ\x22) | (exchange == \x22NYSE\x22) | (exchange == \x22NYSEARCA\x22) | (exchange == \x22NYSEMKT\x22) | (exchange == \x22OTCBB\x22) | (exchange == \x22OTCMKTS\x22)) \x26 (forward_pe_1year \x3E= 0.00) \x26 (forward_pe_1year \x3C= 9.73)]",
"query_for_display" : "[currency == &quot;USD&quot; &amp; ((exchange == &quot;NASDAQ&quot;) | (exchange == &quot;NYSE&quot;) | (exchange == &quot;NYSEARCA&quot;) | (exchange == &quot;NYSEMKT&quot;) | (exchange == &quot;OTCBB&quot;) | (exchange == &quot;OTCMKTS&quot;)) &amp; (forward_pe_1year &gt;= 0.00) &amp; (forward_pe_1year &lt;= 9.73)]"
}
```

I try to replace that characters:

```
//json = json.Replace("\x22", "\"");
//json = json.Replace("\x26", " ");
//json = json.Replace("\x3E", ">");
//json = json.Replace("\x3C", "<");
```

But it also give me same Exception.

Comment: Do you mean `"\\x22"` ... ? Respectifly `@"\x22"`

Comment: That code wouldn't compile. Please provide an example which would actually compile, so we can tell what your JSON really is. If you're getting it from a file and what you've shown is really the content of the file, please say so so that we can reproduce the problem. What's producing the invalid JSON to start with?

Comment: Actually, this json comes from api.

Comment: I have edited my code.

Comment: @Matthias, yes \x22 seems to be issue and other \x characters.

Comment: @Saadi: Well it wouldn't come with escape sequences like that, would it? How did you come up with that source code representation? You should really provide all the relevant information *in the question* - we shouldn't have to keep asking you for more information.

Comment: That's google api response from where you are working Jon. :)
Anyhow, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I *very* much doubt that a Google API is returning invalid JSON. However, as you haven't given us *any information* about how you're calling the API and what you're doing with the response, it's hard to tell. *Please* edit your question with more information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111913/discussion-between-saadi-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt at replacing failed because you were using a C# string literal where `\x` is a C# escape sequence. You *could* have used something like:

```
json = json.Replace("\\x22", "\\\"");
```

... which would replace `\x22` with `\"` in the text.

However, it looks like the text you're receiving actually includes a lot of `\x` escape sequences, so rather than replace them one by one, I'd do it in one go. Here's a short but complete program that works with the link you provided in chat:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("f.txt");
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\\x[0-9a-fA-Z]{2}", ConvertHexEscape);
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(text);
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }

    static string ConvertHexEscape(Match match)
    {
        string hex = match.Value.Substring(2);
        char c = (char) Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
        // Now we know the character we're trying to represent,
        // escape it if necessary.
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\\': return @"\\";
            case '"': return "\\\"";
            default: return c.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, \x22 is quote but I'm not able to replace it using this too:
json = json.Replace("\x22", "\"");

Comment: @Saadi: You are, but you're replacing a double quote with a double quote - it's like saying `json = json.Replace("a", "a");`. What effect do you expect that to have? I don't think you've fully read and understood the second part of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. Thanks!
So, there is no solution to parse the json instead I have to change json string?

Comment: @Saadi: Given what you've said in chat, you've misrepresented your situation to start with.